# Change text in GKPeerPickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, p2p, gamekit

Is it possible to change the default text (something like "looking for other iPhones and iPod touches") in the GameKit's GKPeerPickerController?

I've seen solutions that are completely custom but I was wondering if i can avoid that hassle and just change the default text.

Comment: In looking through the documentation, I'm not sure that you can. In case you haven't seen it though, here's a pretty in-depth sample tank game using GKPeerPickerController: <a href="http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GKTank/index.html">GKTank</a>

Comment: Yes, that's all I've seen and I had a look through the documentation as well.. But I was wondering if there was another route... Because by the documentation it looks like the only way to look for peers is the GKPeerPickerController but I have seen many bluetooth games that have implemented their own "peer pickers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mess with the `GKPeerPickerController`'s view hierarchy which could break with future OS versions.
If you're looking to build your own controller to let the user connect to another device, just forget about using the picker controller and use a simple [`GKSession`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance yourself. Have a look at [Beam It!](http://arctouch.com/beamit/), it's open source (just scroll down a bit).